# Get-childitem and Set-content for Program Files Directory using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

any one could help me with this please.
I have a working script running on windows 10 with psversion 5 and up, tried it on a windows 7 with psversion 2, it works only when I test another file located on Desktop or Downloads but not on those 2 path on the script.

I also did try testing each lines just to verify if they are working, and get-childitem -path "C:.... is showing the desired outputs

```
    Directory: C:\Users\user1\OpenVPN\config\test-UDP-vpn


    Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name
    ----                -------------     ------ ----
   -a---        08/05/2020   8:05 AM        657 test-tls.key
   -a---        08/05/2020   8:12 AM        337 test.ovpn
   -a---        08/05/2020   8:05 AM       3773 test.p12
```

I am running the script as admin(logged on as an admin as well), made sure the file is not being used and already did set-executionpolicy bypass, it runs but not returning any error or whatsoever. appreciate your help

```
$include = @("*ovpn*")
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config","C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\OpenVPN\config\*UDP4*" -Recurse -include $include | 
select-object -expandproperty fullname

foreach ($file in $files) {
$newtext = @()
$contents = get-content $file
foreach ($line in $contents) {
    if ($line -eq "remote 1.1.1.1 1194 udp") {
        $line = $line.Replace("1.1.1.1", "vpn1.domain.com")
                    $newtext += $line
                    $newtext += "remote vpn2.domain.com 1194 udp"
                    $newtext += "remote-random"
            } elseif ($line -eq "resolv-retry infinite") {
                    $line = $line.Replace("resolv-retry infinite", "resolv-retry 60")
                    $newtext += $line
            } else {
                    $newtext += $line
    }
}
$newtext | set-content $file
}
```

Comment: do I understand correctly you are trying to get this working on powershell 2.0?

Comment: it did work but not when I use "C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\config","C:\Users\$env:USERNAME\OpenVPN\config\*UDP4*"

I test a file and hardcoded it, ex. C:\Users\user1\Desktop and it works. not sure if its because of the $env:USERNAME but pretty sure that parameters works on powershell 2 as well

Comment: If you're running it As administrator, do you mean you're running it under elevated privilege as `user1`? or you're running it as a user named `Administrator`?

Comment: I just used user1 as an example, but yeah the user1 I am referring to is the administrator of the pc

Comment: try replacing $env:USERNAME with $($env:USERNAME)